# Quasar Vue Router resolve href named route

Tags: vue-router, quasar

I'm trying to build a href link using vue router

I have the following in routes.js

```js
  const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: () => import("layouts/MainLayout.vue"),
    children: [
      { path: "", component: () => import("pages/IndexPage.vue") },
      {
        path: "download",
        name: "download",
        component: () => import("pages/Download.vue"),
      },
   ]
 }
```

I'm trying to build a href string of "download" which will look like "/#/download"

I tried

```js
<script>
import {useRouter} from "vue-router";
const router = useRouter();

var myhref = router.resolve({name: "download"}).href; // will this give me "/#/download"
</script>
```

I can't seem to get this working. I wonder if this is the correct way to get a url string in Quasar vue router?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? It's not a good technical description of a problem. You need to explain what exactly the issue is.  What happens when this code runs? It's not an obvious syntax error so please explain what console error(s) or wrong behavior you're observing that leads you to say it's not working.

Comment: somehow the website goes blank

Comment: How is that related to anything?  Given the above code, a blank screen could be correct because you've only shown some JavaScript. As far as we know there is nothing being displayed. Can you understand how we can't possibly know these things? **You need to be as detailed as humanly possible when explaining your problem.** Your script code doesn't do anything except set a single `var`.  Is the problem with the var or is the problem with what's on the screen? They seem unrelated.  Are you using the var in some way? Is the value wrong?  What even is the value? You've still told us nothing useful.

Answer (score 0):

useRouter() needs to be inside setup()

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/3379

Comment: In the future, the correct way of expressing your problem is let others know that your code wasn't _just_ "not working" but that you didn't see **any** of your code executing (testing with console.logs). I'm confident you would've seen actual errors in your console that (if you had provided) would've helped you and others clue into the problem. In reality all you needed was to add `setup` keyword to `<script setup>` tag (setup function is older, optional syntax).  The question about how to use router.resolve turned out to be a red herring, no thanks to your extreme lack of debugging details.